# Multiple density plot with plotly in R

Tags: python, r, plotly

I really like this python example:https://plot.ly/python/distplot/ scroll to Plot Multiple Datasets. I would expect the exact same thing is available for R, but it's not documented. Does this mean it's not possible? I came across this example https://community.plot.ly/t/r-plotly-overlay-density-histogram/640/4 which I find far less nice.
This doesn't work but would give an idea about the data I use.

```
# Add histogram data
x1 = data.table(a=rnorm(n = 200,mean = 0,sd = .1), by='Group1')
x2 = data.table(a=rnorm(n = 200,mean = 1,sd = .15), by='Group2')
x3 = data.table(a=rnorm(n = 200,mean = 2,sd = .2), by='Group3')
x4 = data.table(a=rnorm(n = 200,mean = 3,sd = .25), by='Group4')

agg <- rbind(x1,x2,x3,x4)
plot_ly(data = agg, type = "histogram",histnorm, name = "Histogram",group_by='by')
plot_ly(data = agg, type = "density",histnorm, name = "Density",group_by='by')
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure which critical element you are missing in R, but here is a `plotly`-based density plus rug plot example based on your sample data.

This is the static `ggplot` version.

```
require(ggplot2);
gg <- ggplot(agg, aes(x = a, colour = by)) + geom_density() + geom_rug();
```

[image]

And the interactive `ggplotly`ed version including screenshot.

```
require(plotly);
ggplotly(gg);
```

[image]

You can also add a histogram with e.g.

```
gg + geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density.., fill = by), alpha = 0.2, bins = 50)
```

Comment: @Tim_Utrecht Both `ggplotly` and `plot_ly` produce a `plotly` object, so fundamentally **there is no difference**. You can build the same interactive plot without taking the `ggplotly` detour. So I'm not sure what you're after. I've demonstrated how you can build an interactive `plotly`-based density+histogram+rug plot within R, equivalent to the Python-based `plotly` plots you show. Perhaps you can clarify in your original post which elements from Python's `plotly` are missing in R's `plotly` flavours?

Comment: @Tim_Utrecht PS. I've never seen any performance advantage of `plot_ly` vs. `ggplotly`. See also [here](https://community.plot.ly/t/major-performance-difference-between-ggplotly-and-plot-ly/650) for an example where `ggplotly` is actually significantly *faster* than `plot_ly`.